# Find hotspots in a system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses, finite-element-method, fatigue

[image]

In the image, I have a depicted a system which is undergoing fatigue. Using appropriate solver I have determined the life of each nodes and it is stored in a .csv file. Also I have the connectivity of the geometry in a file. My intention is to write a script, so that all the hotspots(some are marked with black rectangles) are found out and written in a file. Note that I want the node numbers under each hotspots to be written together (not node numbers with life values below a certain threshold value written irrespective of the hotspots). Is there any tool available to do this or anyone has any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There are some image analysis algorithms used for tracking that can be used for that (e.g. [Blob tracking with OpenCV](https://learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/)):

1. threshold the image (it should be  very straightoforward in your case). For simplicity assume 0 all values that are not of interest and over 0.5 the pixels/nodes that are of interest
2. the check for the first non zero node, and add it to a  new list.
3. find any adjacent non zero nodes and add it to a list (repeat 3 until there are no adjacent non zero nodes in which case proceed to 4). (scrub the nodes you check from the unchecked nodes)
4. check if the size of the list is greater than certain number of nodes, and then go to 2 (repeat until there are no available nodes).
5. Merge the areas that are closer than a min distance between the nodes.

At the end of the algorithm you should have a few lists with the ids of the nodes that comprise each area of interest. (you can do other things also, like check for ellipticity for each area, and select the ones you are more interested in).

---

Answer (score 0):

You can sum up all pixel columns and mark those that pass a threshold as targets.

Then sum up row pixels the same way.

These darker zones of( Xi, Yi) are your hot spots.

This is roughly a very basic algorithm of Computer Tomography.